# trying to understand postgresql via php database connection sharing

Tags: php, postgresql

To say I am new to PostgreSQL is an understatement.  As such I have spent a great deal of time in the last couple of days going over the various manuals at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php and at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/index.html .

Short form of my question:

Do different users (logged in from separate IP addresses) utilize the same connection to a PostgreSQL data base behind the scenes?

Long form of the question:

In a given php script the database connection `$connection` is defined near the very beginning of script.  That connection is then used throughout the rest of the script via `$GLOBALS['connection']`.  Thus in that script a given user simply reuses the same connection over and over again.

A second user using the same script while logging in from a different location also uses a single copy of the connection.

From the manual (at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php):

`If a second call is made to pg_connect() with the same connection_string as an existing connection, the existing connection will be returned unless you pass PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW as connect_type.`

So, does this mean that both users are sharing the same connection (unless the `PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW` flag is sent)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, every time you run php script - you make new connection unless you're using [persistent connections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) or connection pooler (like [pgbouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) or [pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page)).

`PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW` flag means that if inside one php script you call twice `pg_connect()` with same params you really got one connection unless this flag is set.

Comment: I thank you very much for the help sir/ma'am! (profile gives no clue so take your pick  ;-)  )